# Dataset with numeric output but want to formulate it as classification task

Tags: machine-learning

If I have a dataset with continuous numerical output between 0 and 100. And we want to put the output into 5 bins (0-20,20-40,40-60,60-80,80-100).

The application scenario only needs to identify which bin each row belongs.

So should I consider it as a regression problem, and let regression model predicts a numeric value and then dispatch it to the corresponding bin.

Or should I do preprocessing to the output first, transform them to 5 classes(bins). And using classification algorithm to train it.

Which one is better?  Or any other good ideas?

Comment: [Binning loses information and is discouraged.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/what-is-the-benefit-of-breaking-up-a-continuous-predictor-variable)

Comment: Further, you would be doing some kind of ordinal regression, not a pure classification. I don’t know if it’s worse to call a dog picture a horse or a cat, but I do know that it’s worse to put $19$ in the $40$-$60$ bin than the $20$-$40$ bin. The order matters, and the former should incur more penalty.